# Wordpress admin suddenly not an admin

Tags: wordpress

I have installed a template that I bought, and this template came with a SQL script to run. After I ran it everything works fine, except that the admin user now doesn't have permission to delete articles, media, and other stuff.
I have complete access to the server along with knowledge of PHP and SQL. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you just run the SQL script without checking it first?

Comment: yes, it came with the template.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `wp_user_level` value in the `wp_usermeta` table of your database.  It should probably be 10.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
The original WordPress installation used a prefix for all table names. Apparently, fields in wp_users, wp_options and wp_usermeta whose names begin with "wp_" are supposed to begin with the full prefix.
I changed the table names in the script, but not the actual field names.
Setting the names to the full prefix solved this.

example:
if the prefix is wp_f3refs then wp_user-settings should be wp_f3refs_user-settings.

Thanks everyone for your help.